# Not able to input arabic data in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, arabic

I am trying to add Arabic values in database . When I enter it in database it shows error

> Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xA7\xD9\x84\xD9\x85...' for column 'a_name' at row 1" error

My phpmyadmin server info is

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Make sure your database encoding and collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @fxlacroix is right try this and test it . works fine for hebrew language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inserting Arabic text follow these steps 
1) Go to that table structure
2) Click on change [Where you want to add the Arabic text]
3) Search for  "Collation" and select "utf8_unicide_ci"

In this way you will be able to add the Arabic Inputs in database
Happy Coding
Cheers !!!!!

Comment: `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is better. If you have `utf8mb4_` collation it is [universally better than `utf8_`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236)